# Combine Oracle CONTEXT index and function-based index

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have created the following PRODUCTS table in the Oracle 11g EE database:

```
( ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 ,NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
 ,DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(4000) NOT NULL
 ,CREATED DATE NOT NULL
 ,CHANGED DATE );
```

For this table, the following index of type CTXSYS.CONTEXT was created on the DESCRIPTION field:

```
BEGIN 
  CTX_DDL.CREATE_PREFERENCE ('MY_LEXER', 'BASIC_LEXER'); 
  CTX_DDL.SET_ATTRIBUTE ('MY_LEXER', 'BASE_LETTER', 'YES'); 
END;
/

CREATE INDEX PROD_DESCR_TXT_IDX ON PRODUCTS(DESCRIPTION) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT PARAMETERS ('LEXER MY_LEXER');

BEGIN
  CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX('DOC_DESCR_TXT_IDX', '2M');
END;
/

ANALYZE TABLE DOCUMENTOS_GED COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

This table has many thousands of rows, and I need to query the CONTEXT index to return the rows in descending order by the date of the last change (field CHANGED) and, if this field is null, by the date of creation (field CREATED).

I would like to know if anyone can help me create an index that meets the search criteria for CONTEXT and at the same time bring the results ordered by the "NVL (CHANGED, CREATED) DESC" function, in order to make the result of the following command instantaneous:

```
SELECT *
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE CONTAINS (DESCRIPTION, 'kitchen AND accessories') > 0
ORDER BY NVL(CHANGED, CREATED) DESC;
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: An index can eliminate a sort, only if the execution plan scans the index first then the table. So, a second index in your case will not help, as you don't have a predicate on this column in your SQL. Are you sure that sorting the rows is where you're loosing time in this query?

Comment: Hello gsalem, thanks for the explanation.  I decided to use only the context index in the query and it was enough.